# Meaning of :out in sql

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I have a sql file that I do not understand.

What does :out in the below code means?

This is not usual sql code, where can I learn about this script command?

Thanks!

```
USE [DATABASE_A]
GO
:out D:\xxx\xxxxxx.csv
exec sp_xxxx
go
```

Comment: According to your script in the question, it's just an output in CSV Format...

Answer (score 4):

It is a [sqlcmd script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/edit-sqlcmd-scripts-with-query-editor?view=sql-server-2017):

> By using the Database Engine Query Editor in SQL Server Management Studio you can write and edit queries as SQLCMD scripts. You use SQLCMD scripts when you have to process Windows System commands and Transact-SQL statements in the same script.

```
:out <filename>|stderr|stdout
```

---

> The following example uses a sqlcmd statement to create an output file called testoutput.txt, executes two Transact-SQL SELECT
>
> ```
> :out C:\testoutput.txt  
> SELECT @@VERSION As 'Server Version'
> --- ...
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a command that will be processed by SQLServer Management Studio to save the query results to the named file. It's not a part of the SQL standard, it's particular not only to SQLServer but specifically the SSMS query tool. You couldn't write this in another SQLServer query tool and guarantee it would work